# Parameter estimation in logistic model by negative log-likelihood minimization - R

Tags: r, optimization, data-science, logistic-regression

I am currently attempting to estimate the parameters of a logistic regression model "by hand" on the `iris` dataset via minimisation of cross-entropy. Please note, when I say `iris` dataset, it has been changed such that there are only two classes - Setosa and Other. It was also normalised via the `scale` function:

```
library(dplyr)
library(optimx)
iriso <- iris %>%
  mutate(Species = ifelse(Species == "setosa", "setosa", "other")) %>%
  mutate(Species_n = ifelse(Species == "setosa", 1, 0)) %>%
  as.data.frame()

iriso[,1:4] <- scale(iriso[,1:4])
```

Based on my understanding: should everything be correct, when the optimisation is completed we should obtain the same set of parameters each time - no matter the starting point for the optimisation algorithm. However, the parameter estimates following optimisation are bouncing around:

Some functions being defined:

```
X <- model.matrix(~.,data=iriso[,1:4])
Y <- model.matrix(~0+Species_n,data=iriso)

e <- exp(1)
sigmoid <- function(y){
  1/(1 + e^-y)
}

#w is an array of weights. x is matrix of observations
logistique <- function(w, x){
  sigmoid(
    y = w[1]*x[,1] + w[2]*x[,2] + w[3]*x[,3] + w[4]*x[,4] + w[5]*x[,5]
    )
}

#y is obsrved values
entropie <- function(w, y, x){
  prob_pred <- logistique(w = w, x = x)

  -sum(
    y*log(prob_pred) + (1-y)*log(1-prob_pred)
  ) 
}
```

Optimisation step:

```
for(i in 1:5){
  w0 <- rnorm(n = 5) #set of initial parameters
  optimx(par = w0, fn = entropie,  
         method = "Nelder-Mead",
         y = iriso$Species_n, x = X) %>%
    print()
}
```

I can not seem to understand why I am not obtaining consistent answers. Is there something wrong with the code above? Is there a concept I am not aware of? Something I missed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that you have "complete separation" in your dataset.  With those predictors, you can identify `Species_n` without any error at all.  In this kind of situation, the logistic model has no MLE, it improves more and more as the estimated coefficients get more extreme in the right direction.

The way to detect this is to look at the predicted probabilities or logits.  When I ran your model once, I got estimates that were

```
[1] -21.208757  -3.827454   4.601657  -5.271226 -25.119453
```

These estimates give `y` values (the logits) with absolute values all greater than 13, so the probabilities will be essentially zero or one.

A couple of other minor issues:

1. There's no point in calculating `e^-y`, you can just use `exp(-y)` and will get the same result a bit quicker.
2. Calculating `log(prob_pred)` and `log(1-prob_pred)` directly is likely to be quite inaccurate, or give overflows or underflows.  It's better to work out those expressions analytically so that you don't get rounding error at extreme values of `prob_pred`.  For example, `1-prob_pred = exp(-y)/(1 + exp(-y))`, so `log(1-prob_pred) = -y-log(1 + exp(-y)) = -y-log1p(exp(-y))`.

Comment: Can also check out the detectseparation package.

Comment: It was clear once I googled complete separation .. thanks ! For anybody who sees this .. If you add a penalty (l1 or l2 norm), this stops happening.